# Jasperreport conditional coloured cell without value

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

No matter how silly this requirement is I would like to know your opinion and advices on this topic. Using jasperreport in our system we have requirement to show color instead of an actual value. Is there any chance how to set background color as a reference of value in the cell (e.g. value is #ff0000 which should be set as bg color and value should be hidden)?

Thanks

Comment: `is how to hide the value (e.g. hidden column)?` - In case using jr:table you can use `printWhenExpression`. You should use `printWhenExpression` also for hiding single *textField*

Comment: If I would have the value in the cell as hash color. Is there any chance to set it as background ?

Comment: You can put an empty text field in the cell (using "" as expression), set mode="Opaque" and the net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor property to "#ff0000" or $V{CellColour} (as an expression).  You might also need to set stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" for the element to make sure that it covers then entire cell when it stretches.

Comment: dada67: When doing this dynamically would it be added as "column.addProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor","#000000");" ?

Comment: When using "net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column"

Comment: solved by: column.setStyle(stl.style().setMarkup(Markup.HTML)); and value is the color of <font> tag with rectangle symbol

Comment: I'm not familiar with DynamicReports, but what you probably need is addProperty(""net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"", DRIExpression)